# Netbeans add new Maven remote repository

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jetty, osgi

How to add new remote repo to the NetBeans 7.2 for using with the Dependency window (with repo indexing)?

I found http://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/setting+up+Netbeans+with+the+Magnolia+maven+repository but in 7.2 NB this window moved.

In the Dependency there are no button for adding new remote Maven repos. 
I need to add http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/7.0.0.pre5/ to the NetBeans.

Sorry my bad English.

Thanks, Arthur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit `settings.xml` file in maven and add your repository to it. You should add something like:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>Repository for JDK 1.6 builds</name>
        <url>http://myrepo1:1111/contextpath/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-major</id>
        <name>Repository for JDK 1.6 builds 2</name>
        <url>http://myrepo1:1111/contextpath2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But this code should be wrapped in `profile` tag, I think. For more details you can see [this](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html).
You can find settings file in `$HOME/.m2` directory in linux and same directory in Windows.

Comment: OK, but how to index in NetBeans new (added) repo? And in what settings.xml I must add this? Early I have added to the c:\Program Files\NetBeans Dev 201208070001\java\maven\conf\settings.xml `<mirror>
      <id>central2</id>
      <mirrorOf>central2</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </mirror>` but there are no effect

Comment: My `settings.xml` file placed in `C:\Users\gkuzmin\.m2` directory. I do not know how to force NetBeance to build new index. Idea build new index itself (It seems that Idea monitor `settings.xml` for modifications). Maybe NetBeans will rebuild index after your modification too. BTW, I can point `settings.xml` file in Idea. Can you do it in NB?

Comment: There are no settings.xml in c:\Users\Arthur\.m2\ - it has only repository directory...

Comment: Can you determine which `settings.xml` your IDE use?

Comment: After experiments I found that NB uses Maven's c:\Program Files\NetBeans Dev 201208070001\java\maven\conf\settings.xml settings file. Your answer is correct. And some notes - by default NB uses http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 and there are no need to add new record with the http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 . Eclipse modules poorly organized - for example - jetty uses many other deps what not documented (I haven't found doc's)...

Comment: All jetty dependencies are clearly marked in their respective pom.xml file, no idea what your referring to.

Answer (score 16):

here is easy method-

```
Go to Services>Maven Repositories. Right Click>Add Repository
```

[image]

Comment: where is this supposed to be?